# EDAPlayground: Verilog code "reached maximum runtime"

Tags: verilog, infinite-loop, system-verilog

I have a simple Verilog code for a sequential logic network. It consists of a design and a testbench file; it compiles, but it runs for too long. I'm not sure why; apart from the `clk`, I didn't put any loops in it. Maybe I have some syntax mistakes using the binary numbers. I ran it using the online EDA Playground software; I didn't try it on Xilinx.

> Simulator: Icarus Verilog 0.9.7, compile options: -Wall. "Execution
> interrupted or reached maximum runtime."

This is what the log wrote.

Design file:

```
module hazimodul(
  input clk,
  input rst,
  input ce,
  input x,
  output z
  
);
  

  reg[1:0] all;
  reg[3:0] y;
  reg[0:0] zout;
  
  always@(posedge clk)
  begin
    if(rst)
      begin
        zout <= 1'b0;
        all <= 2'b00;
        y <= 4'b0111;
      end
    else if(ce)
      begin
        if(all == 2'b00)
          begin
            if(x== 1'b0)
              zout<=1'b0;
            else 
              all <=2'b01;
          end
        if(all==2'b01)
          begin
            zout <= y[3:3];
            y <= {y[2:0],y[3:3]};
            if (y == 4'b0111)
              all <= 2'b10;
          end
        if(all==2'b10)
          begin
            if(x == 1'b0)
             all <= 2'b00;
             
          end
      end
  end
  
  assign z = zout;
  
endmodule
```

Test file:

```
module test;

    reg clk;
    reg rst;
    reg x;
    reg ce;
  
  
    // Outputs
    wire z;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    hazimodul uut (
        .clk(clk), 
        .rst(rst), 
      .x(x),
      .ce(ce),
      .z(z)
    );

    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        clk = 0;
        rst = 0;
        x=0;
        ce=0;

        #10;
        rst<=1;
        #20;
        rst<=0;
        #30
        ce<=1;
        #40
        x<=1;
        #80
        x<=0;
        #90
        x<=1;
        
        
    end
    always #5
        clk <=~clk;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the simulator when to stop running.  One way is to use the `$finish` system task, which you can add to your testbench:

```
initial #1000 $finish;
```

Now, the simulation finishes on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/Kyp_).  You can change the `#1000` delay to something more meaningful to your design.

---

Here is an explanation of why your code continues to run.  Your testbench has 2 parallel threads: one `initial` block and one `always` block.  In both threads, you add events to the Verilog event queue.  The `initial` block ends after the last assignment to `x`.

However, the `always` block continues to add events to the event queue, so the simulation never ends.

Adding the second `initial` block with the `$finish` forces the simulation to end, regardless of the infinite `always` block.